# Repeated timing of function

Tags: haskell, monads, timing

I have a very simple function `f :: Int -> Int` and I want to write a program that calls `f` for each `n = 1,2,...,max`. After each call of `f` the (cumulative) time that was used up to that point should be displayed (along with `n` and `f n`). How can this be implemented?

I'm still really new to input/output in Haskell, so this is what I've tried so far (using some toy example function `f`)

```
f :: Int -> Int
f n = sum [1..n]

evalAndTimeFirstN :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO()
evalAndTimeFirstN n max time = 
  if n == max 
   then return () -- in the following we have to calculate the time difference from start to now
   else let str =  ("(" ++ (show n) ++  ", " ++ (show $ f n) ++ ", "++ (show time)++ ")\n") 
         in putStrLn str >> evalAndTimeFirstN (n+1) max time -- here we have to calculate the time difference

main :: IO()
main = evalAndTimeFirstN 1 5 0
```

I don't quite see how I have to introduce the timing here. (The `Int` for `time` probably has to be replaced with something else.)

Comment: It's probably better to delegate benchmarking to a specialized tool, e.g.  http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/

Comment: Thank you for that link! It seems a little bit too difficult for me right now, so I think I still try to stick to a basic approach before using libraries like that one, as I want to learn how to do thinks like that.

Comment: It is difficult to do benchmarking properly and doubly so in a lazy language. If you want accurate results, I do not suggest rolling your own.

Comment: I should probably have emphasized more that this is not about getting accurate benchmarking results, but just an example I constructed in order to learn how to work with these monads, as they are still difficult to understand for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution. In this case we're measuring the "real" time in ms.

```
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

f n = sum[0..n]

getTime = getCurrentTime >>= pure . (1000*) . utcTimeToPOSIXSeconds >>= pure . round

main = do 
    maxns <- getLine 
    let maxn = (read maxns)::Int
    t0 <- getTime 
    loop 1 maxn t0
     where loop n maxn t0|n==maxn = return ()
           loop n maxn t0
             = do 
                 putStrLn $ "fun eval: " ++ (show n) ++ ", " ++ (show $ (f n)) 
                 t <- getTime
                 putStrLn $ "time: " ++ show (t-t0); 
                 loop (n+1) maxn t0
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this. Adapt the following basic example as needed for your recursive function.

```
import Data.Time.Clock
import Control.Exception (evaluate)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter a number"
  n <- readLn
  start <- getCurrentTime
  let fact = product [1..n] :: Integer
  evaluate fact  -- this is needed, otherwise laziness would postpone the evaluation
  end <- getCurrentTime
  putStrLn $ "Time elapsed: " ++ show (diffUTCTime end start)
  -- putStrLn $ "The result was " ++ show fact
```

Uncomment the last line to print the result (it gets very large very quickly).

Comment: I have found snippets like that one so far, but I don't see how to apply this if you want to measure the times for all `n=1,2,...,max` and not for just a slinge `n`, so you'd need some kind of `loop` over those `n`, but that is the point where I am stuck.

Comment: @flawr But your own code does such a loop, using recursion. It's probably not the best style, but it works. I'd introduce the calls to `getCurrentTime` in your code.